# Remove query string from URL after some period of time in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hi all I am trying to remove the query string from my url after some period of time in php I have 2 pages one is login-issue.php in that page after user submit the from it will redirect to login.php page with query string like below

```
    if ($mail->Send()) {

     Header( 'Location: login.php?message=success' );
}
```

In login.php the message will appear with that query string

```
    if(isset($_GET['message']))
    { 
$successMessage= "Your Request has been sent to Admin.you will get mail with in 24hrs"; 
}
```

I want to remove that query with that success message after some interval of time (1 min).

Can anyone help me how can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP can't do anything in the client. PHP is a server side language that get's executed on the server. The result of that will then get sent to the client, where any HTML, CSS and JS will get executed/rendered.

Comment: okay how can i do that in javascript..

Comment: Instead of passing the message through the URL, you could use sessions. When the action is done, before you redirect the user, set a session value, like: `$_SESSION['msg'] = 'Your request has been .....';`. Then, on the page you redirect to, if the session is set and has a value, print the message and then unset it: `unset($_SESSION['msg']);`. That's usually called "flash sessions".

Comment: in login-issue.php page i have done like this if ($mail->Send()) {
     $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Your request has been .....';
     Header( 'Location: login.php' );
}

Comment: and in login.php page if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
 { 
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
} but i didn't get amy message

Comment: Don't forget that you need to start the session for each request you want to use the session or it won't exist. Just put session_start(); in the top of the files and you should be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHP` by itself can't deal with client-side manipulations, so we need to use `JavaScript` to do the task.

```
setTimeout(function() {
 history.pushState('', '', 
 location.href.split('?')[0]);
}, 60000); // 1 min = 1000 ms * 60 = 60000
```

**Explanation:**
We said to `JavaScript` that I want to execute `history.pushState('', '', 
 location.href.split('?')[0]);` after 1 minute using `setTimeout` method, this method belongs to the `window` object (if you're using a browser) and as `window` is the object that holds everything so writing `window.setTimeout(...)` is optional `JavaScript` knows we're referencing `window` even we didn't write it. So we split the current `URL` by `?` character we get an array as a return and we replace the current `URL` by the first column in that table.

With that the `query string` will be removed from the `URL` without refreshing the page.

**EDIT:**

to show the message in a `p` tag that we will be deleted after 1 min alongside with changing the `URL`, change this:

```
if(isset($_GET['message'])) { 
    $successMessage= "Your Request has been sent to Admin.you will get mail with in 24hrs"; 
}
```

into this:

```
if(isset($_GET['message'])) { 
    $successMessage= '<p id="message">Your Request has been sent to Admin.you will get mail with in 24hrs</p>'; 
}
```

and then change the above `JavaScript` that I gave it to you with this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
     history.pushState('', '', 
     location.href.split('?')[0]);
     var msg = document.getElementById('message');
     msg.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}, 60000); // 1 min = 1000 ms * 60 = 60000
```

And now you **MUST** to put that script in script tag just before `</body>`

**So another EDIT to meet your needs:**

just put this script in a `script` tag without changing anything else in your `PHP` code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
 window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
}, 60000);
```

with that, the page will automatically be refreshed after 1 minute, thus no `GET['message']` will be included and therefore no message will be displayed in the page.

Hope I pushed you further.
Am here if you want any further explanations.

Comment: which page i need to place this script login.php page?

Comment: in the login page put in a script tag.

Comment: query string has removed and message was still there how can i remove the message too

Comment: it stills there because there is a get variable. we didn't remove the get variable here we just remove a part from the URL.

Comment: so there is no way to remove message

Comment: there is ! put it in p tag for example give it and ID of "message" for example and then remove it.

Comment: is it posiible to refresh the page when query string removed so by that time message also will remove rite?

Comment: I edited my answer so it will remove both the message and the query string after 1 minute.

Comment: query string has removed but message not removed

Comment: if you want I can edit my answer to provide for you a way to redirect to the same page without the query string and thus no need for removing the `p` tag that holds the message because it will not be showed(because there is no `GET['message']` variable).

Comment: ok then thats fine refresh the page then query string has to disappear and message also

Comment: @user200 I edited my post, added a script that refreshes the page after 1 minute without displaying the message in the page again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178440/discussion-between-ths-and-user200).

Comment: can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057336/window-has-to-close-if-user-is-not-click-on-a-button-up-to-20-seconds-in-javascr

Comment: @user200 what's in there ?

Comment: i am showing a one popup if user is inactive in page up to 10 seconds so after that if user didn't click on the continue button up to seconds i want to close the window

Comment: @user200 I'll check it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are need that:

```
setTimeout(() => location.search = "", 2000);
```

`2000` - is a delay in milliseconds.

You should place that code in [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag at the bottom of your page.

Comment: You might want to inform the OP where this should go (and what language it is).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - It is JavaScript (ES6)

Comment: @mplungjan - I know, but the OP might not. The answer should include that, and where this should go. We can't assume that the OP or future visitors will recognize it. This is, in my opinion, a half-answer.

Comment: You can add some expression at PHP and add this code to the bottom of your page.

Comment: this keeps the `?` in the url